# How can I change the location of a photo?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can I change the location of a photo?

How can I change the location of a photo?

How can I change the location of a photo?

my script is :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
sizeIcons = 30
f1 = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(0, 0, 0, 0))
f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')


label1 = Label(f1)

myimg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\align.left.png').resize((sizeIcons, sizeIcons), Image.ANTIALIAS))
label1['image'] = myimg1
label1.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.50, anchor=CENTER)
label1.pack()

label2 = Label(f1)
myimg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\align.center.png').resize((sizeIcons, sizeIcons), Image.ANTIALIAS))
label2['image'] = myimg2
label2.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.50, anchor=CENTER)
label2.pack()

label3 = Label(f1)
myimg3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\align.right.png').resize((sizeIcons, sizeIcons), Image.ANTIALIAS))
label3['image'] = myimg3
label3.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.50, anchor=CENTER)
label3.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I want to change the location of label1,label2,label3.

and

and

Why does not the button appear?

Why does not the button appear?

Why does not the button appear?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
sizeIcons = 30
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
f1 = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(0, 0, 0, 0))
f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
label1 = Label(f1)
myimg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\align.left.png').resize((sizeIcons, sizeIcons), Image.ANTIALIAS))
label1['image'] = myimg1
label1.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.50, anchor=CENTER)
label1.grid()   
def a ():
    raise_frame(f2)

next1 = ttk.Button(f1, text='Next', command=a, default='active')
next1.grid(sticky=NW, padx=160, pady=320)

f2 = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(0, 0, 0, 0))
f2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

label2 = Label(f2)
myimg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\align.center.png').resize((sizeIcons, sizeIcons), Image.ANTIALIAS))
label2['image'] = myimg2
label2.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.50, anchor=CENTER)
label2.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Why does not the button appear?
Why does not the button appear?
Why does not the button appear?

Comment: If you use 3 Labels in your code, it doesn't mean that you can ask the same question thrice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use specify height and width in `ttk.Frame(root, padding=(0, 0, 0, 0))`
Also don't use all the location managers (grid, pack, place). Use one of them!

Try the below code:

Adjust the **x** and **y** position in `place` to move the images and adjust the **height** and **width** according to your need:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
sizeIcons = 30
f1 = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(0, 0, 0, 0), height=800, width=900)
f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')


label1 = Label(f1)
myimg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\align.left.png').resize((sizeIcons, sizeIcons), Image.ANTIALIAS))
label1['image'] = 'myimg1'
label1.place(x=500, y=50, anchor=CENTER)


label2 = Label(f1)
myimg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\align.center.png').resize((sizeIcons, sizeIcons), Image.ANTIALIAS))
label2['image'] = 'myimg2'
label2.place(x=50, y=50, anchor=CENTER)


label3 = Label(f1)
myimg3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\align.right.png').resize((sizeIcons, sizeIcons), Image.ANTIALIAS))
label3['image'] = 'myimg3'
label3.place(x=75, y=50, anchor=CENTER)
root.mainloop()
```